# BrowserTest: Need to select a dynamic value from dropdrown

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm running a Fitnesse/Slim/BrowserTest page that selects from a dropdown, but I know only the index I want, not the text itself. Does browser support selecting indexes? I tried:

```
| select | index=1 | for | id=selectSnapshot |
```

But it never finds the element - it just times out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting based on index is not supported. But I believe you could get the result you are looking for with keyboard commands.
Something like:

```
|click|drop-down|
|press|down|
|press|enter|
```